# Naming a recursive association entity

Tags: database-design, naming

For my current project, I need to create a database table to store a recursive association.  I've done a lot of searching and have read answers on questions, such as [Naming convention for associative entity](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/68505/naming-convention-for-associative-entity) and [How do you name your many-to-many relationship tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631850/how-do-you-name-your-many-to-many-relationship-tables), but they don't discuss the case of a recursive relationship.

My company ships out inventory, and they want some parts to automatically include other parts on an order.  For example, an order for a Widget will automatically have a Widget Guide added automatically.

The table's schema will basically just be two columns, each a foreign key to the `InventoryProduct` table.  My struggle has been naming this table and these columns.  I've considered something like:

```
InventoryAssociation
--------------------
ParentInventoryProductId : int, FK
ChildInventoryProductId : int, FK
```

But I don't feel like "InventoryAssociation" is a great name for the table/entity, nor do I think the association between the two inventory products is really a parent/child relationship.

Does anyone have suggestions for better names?  Thanks!

Comment: How about `InventoryProductId` and `AutomaticallyIncludedInventoryProductId`? The table could be something like `InventoryProductAutomaticInclusions`.

Comment: While I think the question has merit, it is asking for an opinion that would be too broad to answer. [Why was my question closed as too broad?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6490/)

Comment: @AdamZuckerman Heaven forbid we ask for an opinion for *naming* in programming.  You may want to check out the [naming] tag... there's 23 pages of questions you should go close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are better patterns for describing hierarchical data structures for example the [nested set model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model). (In your case you probably need a tree identifier because you want to describe multiple trees.)

About the naming. If you are not sure you describe a parent/child relationship, then it is better to describe a graph with nodes and links. In your case the nodes are the InventoryProducts and the links are the relationships between them. So I'd use

```
InventoryRelationships
--------------------
SourceInventoryProductId : int, FK
TargetInventoryProductId : int, FK
```

and possibly another fields to describe the type of the relationship. (Btw. a graph database like neo4j would be better if you want to work on huge graphs.) If there is only a single relationship type. Then it should be included by the table name.

Currently I cannot find a better term that the inventory products are related to each other, but I'll check the link relations and some other vocabs, maybe I find a better solution. In the schema.org vocab there is a [Product/isAccessoryOrSparePartFor](http://schema.org/isAccessoryOrSparePartFor) property. So maybe the

```
InventoryAccessories
--------------------
InventoryProductId : int, FK
AcessoryInventoryProductId : int, FK
```

or something like that would work for you. If not, then in your case I would try other business related RDF vocabs.

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer since while I don't need anything as complicated as a full graph, I do like your second suggestion.  It's given me a few ideas that I'll mull over.  And, since my question has been cut off by the infamous Stack Exchange moderation, I probably won't see any other answers anyway.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Shit happens... Upvoted. ;-)